# Karaf OSGi services goes down unexpectedly

Tags: apache-karaf

I am new to Karaf..

My apache karaf container runs around 20 OSGi bundles. Things work properly most of the time, but at times when the services are not accessible, i open the karaf console, I see that some of the bundles are in "Resolved" state, which originally was in "Active". What could probably cause a service in "Active" state to come down to "Resolved" state?

Thanks in advance

Comment: a bit more details could be really helpful ;). Like which version of Karaf you're using, what kind of bundles these are. Do they use blueprint, do they use activators, do you spawn threads ...

Comment: I am using 
* Karaf 2.3.0
* Deploying eclipse plugin projects as my bundles
* Use activators to start the bundles

Comment: What does the logfile say? I think one of your bundles most likely runs into an error and de-activates itself, taking all others down with it.

Comment: There is nothing much for this that i find in the logs. Funny part is, not all bundles are going down. I keep working on the UI and suddenly some submit actions or pages stop working. At times it is only one, sometimes more. But not all services go down.

Comment: Hmm, sounds like you have a bug in your software, like one of your Actions does trigger a stop of a bundle.